# Is there a obfs4 package for ARMv5?

Tags: bridge, pluggable-transports, obfsproxy, obfs4proxy

I'm trying to install obfs4 support on a bridge. But I cant find the right package to install. Can anyone help me find it?

Running [archlinux for arm](https://archlinuxarm.org/) on a [pogoplug v2](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv5/pogoplug-v2-pinkgray)

Thanks!

Comment: a source compilation is your way : GO language + OBFS4

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to build it natively, as per [the README here](https://github.com/yawning/obfs4) or you can try to cross-compile from another architecture to armv5 using [the method here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GoArm).

For example

```
    export GOARCH=arm
    export GOARM=5
    mkdir ~/goarm
    export GOPATH=~/goarm
    go get -u github.com
    go get git.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/obfs4.git/obfs4proxy
```

should result in an ARMv5 obfs4proxy binary in `~/goarm/bin/obfs4proxy`

*edit: Looking at some of the dependencies, there maybe issues with cryptographic operations that have been optimized in assembly. It does seem to have ARM assembly though.*